# Should I quit my job designing mobile apps now that its used for giving the location of parties?

Tags: work, technology

I am a software engineer and I work for a company that mostly builds eCommerce mobile apps and the owner of the company is a Muslim. The problem now I am facing is that he has taken up a project for an app that gives location of parties, let people join that party and post picture related to that party or event.

I know working on this kind of project is haram, so my question is should I resign from the company or not? One thing I know is that if I will stay then I will have to work on this project there is no other option.

Comment: What makes you think it is haram?

Comment: The app will be used to locate rave parties. IMO helping someone finding that kind of  a party is a sin.

Comment: Everyone is responsible for his/her own actions on the day of Judgement. The responsibility of organizing and participating in such events lies with the people who do that. Consider the possibility that this very same platform can be used to organize charity or other good events. This opportunity will be lost if you don't make such site. If someone sells a haram thing on the eCommerce app, will it make you guilty?

Answer (score 1):

AoA.
Firstly know that action is based on intentions and that you would be judged based on your intentions. I am no scholar. but my assumption is that literally parties are not haram in Islam. It becomes haram when there's no Hijab, immodesty, music, etc involved. A party could be a wedding party, an Iftar party , Eid party, etc. So what is your intention as well as the owner's while developing this mobile app is necessary in deciding whether it's Haram and Halal.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i am not the scholar but in my personals views because i am webdeveloper also and muslim too.there is condition you make the app to user right or wrong its depend on user.if the muslim use the right way to search the event where will teach about quran or sunna.now you got rewards.its makes you sense.other wise my advise kindly contact to nearest alim who know the what is the boundaries of islam.

Comment: I know the app could be used in a better way, but I know for sure that the client's target audience is the youth that are unable to use facebook for this purpose because of the family members added on their account. Here is a line from the requirement document
"I feel the best way to take advantage of the location aspect of people accessing social networks through mobile devices is to tap
into what young people do naturally: go out, have fun, listen to music and dance."

Answer (score 0):

I think people have to choose their way themselves.but when you do something for interesting them in wrong way, you have to answer about them in last day.
But in this case, you are not the determinant of app's direction.
I think if you just develop things like UI and ... there is no problem.but going further is haram.
again,I'm not a islam schoolar so better to look for more proofed answers

Comment: I am a backend developer, I am very much involved in the architecture of the app.